# What is the cleanest approach to infinite horizontal scroll wheel

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scroll

[image]

[image]

The goal is to create an infinite horizontal wheel. My plan is use the first image as such: begin by displaying all of the first image. When the user swipes right, animate the image being pushed off the right of the screen and then display the pushed off part of the image as if its being pushed onto the the left like a wheel.

What would be the easiest approach to this? I'm not asking for code, just some starting help with the main idea.

Comment: Exactly what should happen when the red line reaches one side of the view?

Comment: Also your images don't match.

Comment: When the red line moves past the right side it should appear on the left side and continue moving to the right to give the idea of a scrolling wheel.

Comment: OK but of course that's not how a wheel would work. It would take a long time for the line to come around the back... :)

Comment: Unless the wheel had multiple red lines uniformly distributed :). Perhaps its an odd wheel, but how might I approach this?